# How to get serverside filename in clientside while using AsyncFileUpload

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, scriptmanager, asyncfileupload

I'm using AsyncFileUpload for uploading files, before saving file on server, i rename the selected file. How can I get this new file name in the client side?

```
<asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload1" runat="server" 
                    OnUploadedComplete ="UploadFile1" 
                    OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete" ThrobberID="myThrobber" />
```

Client-side script:

```
   <script>
   function uploadComplete(sender, args) {
         var fileExtension = args.get_fileName();
   }
   </script>
```

Server-side script:

```
Protected Sub UploadFile1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim fileuploadreceive1 As String = AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName
    Dim strExtn As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileuploadreceive1).ToLower

    Dim filename1 As String = Path.GetFileName(fileuploadreceive1)
    filename1 = "uld" & Math.Round(Rnd() * 2366) & filename1 'changing original file name
    Dim fileuploadpath1 As String = Server.MapPath("~") & "\gallery\"

    If (strExtn = ".png") Or (strExtn = ".jpg") Or (strExtn = ".gif") Then
        AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(fileuploadpath1, filename1))

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

were you talking about something like:

```
<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/images/MemoEditor_ABCtoolbar.png") %>
```

This will get the servers name for it, and then pass what it is called to the client.  You can wrap that in some simple javascript or in this example, put it in the src of an image tag.

```
var x = '<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/images/MemoEditor_ABCtoolbar.png") %>';
```

Comment: I'm talking about `args.get_fileName();` it returns original `filename1`